# Which Compilers to use?

Tags: compiler-construction, codeblocks, gnu, dev-c++

There have been a lot of people saying that Codeblock and GNU are the best compilers. I am a beginner at C/C++ programming. Currently I am using Dev C++, so does it make a difference to which compiler I use? And I use Windows 8.1 as my OS, if that is a deciding factor..
Thanks for any help in advance :)

Comment: Requests for recommendations are considered off-topic here. This might be a good question for http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ -- but first check whether this question has already been asked there.

Comment: @KeithThompson Thanks.. I'll keep that in mind. I'm new here. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a difference in performance and the supported language features.

If you investigate the DEV c++ you will notice that it is no longer maintained. New features will not be added and bugs will not be fixed.

Having said that - DEV C++ is perfectly fine for the first year or so. Afterwards you may want to switch to a different tool chain.

Getting into a discussion on this topic here is not encouraged since this is not a discussion forum. But to give you a hint you may to look into visual studio express or eclipse CDT. Both are also free to use.